# Bootstrap - btn-group-justified

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Eu queria carregar a página com um dos botões "selecionado" (ativado), como se fosse um Radion-Button. Como se fosse um "selected".
Alguém sabe como fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Foi muito fácil.
Abasta colocar o complemento "active" na frente da class "btn-primary":

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
  <a class="btn btn-primary active">Todas</a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary">Abertas</a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary">Pendentes</a>
</div>
```